# How do I create default custom data when changing contact subtypes via the API?

Tags: custom-fields, api, sub-types

If I use the API to give someone a new contact subtype it doesn't create a row in any relevant custom data tables and populate the default values. Does anyone have a good way to handle this? I have smart groups that hang off the default custom data, but new contacts aren't going into them.

I'm trying to dig through for a handy createRelevantCustomDataFromSubtype function but can't see anything yet.

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how it typically works, but in your same api call just populate one of the fields in each relevant custom data group with a blank '' and that should fill in the rest.